# how can I export a vector shadow in illustrator to place into photoshop as a smart object?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I know you can export the asset as a PSD and open it in Photoshop. Is there a more seamless way?

Update:  I'm an idiot.  Someone else created the logo, and the shadow was it's own layer on multiply and not a normal drop shadow effect.

Comment: Please provide more detail.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but getting shadow from illustrator to photoshop, seems kinda dumb to be honest. It doesn't take longer than few seconds to use layer style to create a shadow in photoshop and once you do that, you can apply it to multiple elements and it will adapt to their specific size and shape.

Comment: I realize you can create a drop shadow in many different and often times easy ways within photoshop. My question becomes pertains to and becomes more relevant when for example, you are given a logo created in illustrator by someone else that has a drop shadow and wanting to move it over to photoshop.  It's a drop shadow that needs to stay exact.

Comment: Fair enough, but I still don't quite understand. Were you only able to get the logo to photoshop, but not its shadow? What I would do is either what Scott suggests or even more likely would be that I'd have or make a pdf file that I would open up where I need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. Just copy сmd+C in illustrator and paste in photoshop. Pasted object in photoshop will be smart object. This smart object will be editable - after double click on it in layers palette in photoshop it wiil be opened with illustrator. 
Mini tut.
[image]

Comment: Thanks but that's not the issue.  The logo being pasted has the logo appear on white.  Not transparent.  Make sense?

Comment: I'm attached mini tutorial to previous comment. Another trick is just select object in illustrator and drag it into photoshop document.

Comment: ok that works perfectly well, just as it should have.  I just realized the problem I was having is due to the fact that the vector logo given to me had the drop shadow created as a layer that was a blend that needs to be set to multilply at all times.  Your solution works great for a normal drop shadow effect.  I thought I was going crazy cause yes, it should have been as easy as copy and paste or dragging.  I've done that a billion times. I think my solution now is I must import the shadow layer separately and put only that layer itself, on multiply.  It just feels really hack like now.

Comment: yes. solution for object with that shadow in separate importing.

Answer (score 0):

Copy in Illustrator.. Paste in Photoshop.

You've not really given much detail in your question.